# How can I add multiple webviews (on different pages) to one app? (iPhone/iPad)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, uiwebview, ios5

I'm trying to add several UIWebViews (on different pages) in my iPhone app, I added the UI part of it, but I can't figure out how to program them to load separate pages. I watched a YouTube video on how to add a webview, and the method works for a single webview, but when I try to add another to the detail view delegate, it tells me that I'm re-defining a couple different items. Anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

All the `UIWebView` delegate methods pass you a reference to the `UIWebView` instance that the delegate call is relevant for.

So for example if you have two `UIWebView`s called `webView` and `webView2` then you can do something like this:

```
- (void) webView:(UIWebView *)webView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    if (webView == self.webView1) {
        // Do something for webView1
    }
    else if (webView == self.webView2) {
        // Do something for webView2
    }
}
```

Same applies to all other delegate methods for `UIWebView`.